# Mailchimp *sometimes* sends "No RSS items found." emails

Tags: wordpress, rss, mailchimp

I have a wordpress site and link Mailchimp to the RSS feed. Sometimes Mailchimp sends an email with the correct heading but "No RSS items found." for the body, despite there being text in the RSS feed.
Has anyone else had this issue or know of a solution?

Comment: I'm actually on with MailChimp support for this very issue right now and not getting very far on a) how it is caused and b) how to avoid it.  What is the content of your campaign?  Are you using RSSFEED/RSSITEMS merge tags or FEEDBLOCK?  Is this a regular campaign or an RSS-based campaign?

Comment: Thanks, Brian!
I'm using FEEDBLOCK tags and it's an RSS-based campaign.
Interesting, now that you mention it - the title is RSSITEM and hasn't had a problem. Maybe it's the FEEDBLOCK.

Comment: Is the FEEDBLOCK using the exact same URL as the RSS?  If they're different at the moment (according to MailChimp support) there's no way to conditionally check a FEEDBLOCK won't display the 'no RSS items found' and a slow site or temporary issue with that feedblock URL can be the cause.  If they are the same can use the RSSITEMS merge tags instead: http://kb.mailchimp.com/merge-tags/rss-merge-tags

Comment: The FEEDBLOCK and RSS URLs were the same. I've changed to RSSITEM and so far (1 day), no problems.

Comment: Good to hear!  Summed it up in an answer :)  Will add/edit if I hear more from MailChimp on avoiding that error with FEEDBLOCK merge tags in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the URL is the same for your RSS campaign and your FEEDBLOCK, try switching to the RSSITEMS merge tags instead.  From what I can see and from speaking with MailChimp support, this should avoid the issue by not having MailChimp do a separate request for the feed which might timeout and cause the error.

Of course if there is a performance issue with fetching the RSS feed the campaign may not send at all some days, but at least you should avoid the ugly "no rss items found" error.

Comment: MailChimp has just confirmed by email that there is an issue with RSS campaigns and the error message sometimes happening, and they are working on a fix.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the reason you get "No RSS items found" in your Mailchimp feed (even though it's a valid feed) is because a special character has slipped in there when the story title or text has been copied from a word doc etc. - e.g. special quote marks like ¨ instead of ". Just go to the post and change the special character to the standard one by typing over it manually from your keyboard, and then your feed should be working again in no time.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, the reason why you are getting "No RSS items found." is because you correctly tagged the heading with *|RSSITEM|* though when it comes to body you are using *|FEEBLOCKS|* hence the error.

For you to receive title, text and link you need to change FEEDBLOCKS to RSSITEMS. Below is  a working example for mail-chimp design template that you can use or edit to include what you want displayed.

```
*|RSS:POSTS|*

You might also be interested in our previous posts below

*|RSS:RECENT|*

Sharing is Loving

*|RSSITEM:SHARE:Twitter,Facebook,Linkedin,Pinterest,WhatsApp|*

*|END:RSSITEMS|*
```

See how mail-chimp displays the above code https://us20.campaign-archive.com/?u=61cb8c2e1dff4b3d3c746c04c&id=29046da882

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).